# Receiving multiple bytes from an RPi using the i2c protocol

Tags: serial, i2c, raspberrypi

Trying to send bytes from an RPi as a master to an Arduino as a slave.

The send uses the `write_byte(addr, value)` function and seems to be working perfectly.

The Arduino however has issues with separating the received bytes into individual values.

I want to use the RPi to dictate when data is sent so I just need the Arduino to listen on wire.available.

Using the wire.onreceive event function I can have a separate function which has:

```cpp
int var = wire.read()
Serial.print(var)   //for monitoring read byte
```

This code shows that the bytes being received are the right ones however, when I try something like

```cpp
ledData[0] = wire.read();
ledData[1] = wire.read();
ledData[1] = wire.read();
etc
etc
...
```

This returns wildly different values as if the bytes are getting mixed up. Can anyone help me to specifically intake 16 bytes into array indexes for use in the main loop function.